# Core Data Models non-stored models and keynotes?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, core-data, data-modeling

i'm struggling a bit with this subject since I come from the world of PHP where you don't have anything like "Core Data" (as far as i know).

Until today, when i needed a data model for saving data from the server , lets say i got some users from an API, i would create an NSObject class called "MyAppUser" , and on the .h file would have the properties for that data and synthesize it in the .m , and then just use that class for arranging my server-data in nice neat objects.

I read a bit about Core Data , and it seems its mainly for actually storing the data in some sort of database, which isn't what i want. What i want is actually just have organized objects with data from my server returned to me. Could i do this with Core Data? just have objects but without actually managing them and storing them ?

Thank you and sorry if my question is a bit "scattered" :)
Shai.

Comment: in what format does the server provide the data?

Comment: JSON, thats not the point though , i'm trying to understand what is the best way to just store objects from wherever into objects in Objective C. Is creating properties inside regular NSObjects the right way, or should i use Core Data, and if Core-Data, what would be the correct way there? :)

Comment: ok, because if you are using JSON you can generate the class files automatically. It makes it very easy to store the data and saves a lot of coding effort

Comment: Sounds interesting, how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct - core data is a persistence framework. It is designed to help you store and retrieve data between sessions. It's not worth the overhead (IMO) for transient data. Use a custom object for storage, or even just an `NSDictionary`.

Comment: Thank you , thats what i thought . Appreciate your comment :)